# mysql need to show all months data for the selected year

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I got stuck with my query. I need to show monthl (current + previous) records.

Let's take below example for year 2014:-

I have 7 records in the month 03(March)

I have 2 records in the month 04(April)

So total records in year 2014 is 9.

Now we come to year 2015:-

I need to show all records in Jan(No new records added in database), This should be 9.

**My Query shows 0.**

I need to show all records in Feb(5 new records added in database), This should be 14.

**My query shows 5.**

*Query works fine when I am checking for month 03 and year 2014, showing all 7 records. but not for all conditions.*

> I am calling same query for all months(01-12).

```
SELECT count(pkID) as TRecords 
FROM   students 
WHERE  (fkCategoryID ='56' 
OR     fkSecondaryCategoryID ='56' 
OR     fkOptionalCategoryID ='56') 
AND    MONTH(`DateAdded`) <='1' 
AND    YEAR(`DateAdded`) <='2015';
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
SELECT 
   MONTH(`DateAdded`), 
   YEAR(`DateAdded`),
   count(pkID) as TRecords 
FROM students 
WHERE 
    fkCategoryID ='56' OR 
    fkSecondaryCategoryID ='56' OR 
    fkOptionalCategoryID ='56'
group by 
    MONTH(`DateAdded`), YEAR(`DateAdded`)
```

Or maybe some more filters. Your question is not all clear.

Or maybe:

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#students') is not null drop table #students


create table #students 
    (
    pkID int,
    DateAdded date
    )

 insert #students values 
      (1, '20100101'),
      (1, '20100201'),
      (1, '20100301'),
      (1, '20100401'),
      (1, '20100501'),
      (1, '20100601'),
      (2, '20100101'),
      (2, '20100201'),
      (2, '20100301')

SELECT 
   MONTH(DateAdded), 
   YEAR(DateAdded),
   count(pkID) as TRecords,
   sum(count(pkID)) over(partition by YEAR(DateAdded) order by MONTH(DateAdded))
FROM #students 
group by 
    MONTH(DateAdded), YEAR(DateAdded)
 order by 2,1
```

Or maybe:

```
SELECT 
   MONTH(s.DateAdded), 
   YEAR(s.DateAdded),
   count(s.pkID) as TRecords,
   (select count(pkID)
    from #students
        where 
            YEAR(DateAdded) <= YEAR(s.DateAdded) 
            and MONTH(DateAdded) <= MONTH(s.DateAdded)
   )
FROM #students s
group by 
   MONTH(s.DateAdded), YEAR(s.DateAdded)
```

Comment: I need to show all 12 months data for the selected year.

Comment: Like Jan 17000 Feb 18000 Mar 19500

Comment: Your answer is not correct, please check my posted query and post correct answer if you know

Comment: So is it a 'month to date' value what you want? so probably a window-fuction is the best.

Comment: I just select year then I need to show data for all months(Jan-Dec) for this year.

Comment: see my edit: This is 'year to date'. Did you get the idea?

Comment: You're using Window (Analytic) functions! Still beta in MySQL!

Comment: Maybe you can do it with a correlated subquery then?

Comment: @Christian4143, I resolve my problem. Thanks for try to help

Answer (score 0):

Finally after searching a lot on this I resolved this.

```
SELECT COUNT(pkID) as TRecords 
FROM students 
WHERE (fkCategoryID = 56 OR fkSecondaryCategoryID = 56 OR fkOptionalCategoryID = 56)
AND DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded, '%Y-%m') <= '2015-01';
```